ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b'0f 18 ' in Python with GATT
I am working with Python and the GATT library, pxexpect to handle some data, but I am encountering an issue when trying to convert a hexadecimal value to an integer. Here’s the specific error I’m seeing:
print(int(gatt.before, 16)),
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b'0f 18 '

This is the code which produces the error..
print(int(gatt.before, 16)),
print("%")

The variable gatt.before contains a value b'0f 18 '. It appears that this is a bytes object representing a hexadecimal value with spaces. However, int() with base 16 expects a string without spaces
What I’ve Tried:

Removing Spaces:
I tried stripping the spaces, but that didn't solve the issue.
Decoding:
I used .decode('utf-8') to convert the bytes object to a string, but that didn’t help either.


Did you try doing both of those things?

I agree with @user2357112, combining both of the operations (i.e., decoding and then stripping whitespace) will solve the problem.

I tried stripping the spaces, but that didn't solve the issue I don't see how that is possible.  Stripping the spaces should have solved it.  You must have made some other mistake.  Please show us the exact code you used to strip the spaces.

I suspect this is an XY Problem.
You are asking about converting the byte string to an integer, but the fact you have a GATT characteristic value in this format suggests you have already gone wrong in how you are getting the value. Most Python Bluetooth libraries will not return a value in such a format.
You haven't said what you expect b'0f 18' to be as an integer. Most values in Bluetooth are represented in little endian format so I would expect the answer to be 6,159.
However you are doing int('0f18', 16) will give 3,864.
The use of pexpect is also a red flag that you have taken a wrong path.
Given the information in your question, I have outlined the possible steps to convert the byte string to an integer:
# Assuming gatt.before is a byte string returned from a pexpect command.
# Here represented by gatt_before
gatt_before = b'0f 18 '

# Decode the byte string to a regular string
hex_string = gatt_before.decode('utf-8')

# Convert the string value into bytes value
byte_obj = bytes.fromhex(hex_string)

# Convert the bytes values to an integer with control of endianness and signed.
integer_value_le = int.from_bytes(byte_obj, byteorder='little', signed=False)
integer_value_be = int.from_bytes(byte_obj, byteorder='big', signed=False)

print(f'{integer_value_le=:}')
print(f'{integer_value_be=:}')
print(f'int(gatt_before, 16)={int(byte_obj.hex(), 16)}')


which gave the following output:
integer_value_le=6159
integer_value_be=3864
int(gatt_before, 16)=3864


NOTE: this experiment was done with Python 3.10.12


# Assuming gatt.before is a byte string returned from a GATT command. Here represented by gatt_before
gatt_before = b'0f 18 '

# Decode the byte string to a regular string
hex_string = gatt_before.decode('utf-8')

# Remove spaces and any other non-hexadecimal characters
cleaned_hex_string = ''.join(hex_string.split())

# Convert the cleaned-up string to an integer
integer_value = int(cleaned_hex_string, 16)

print(integer_value)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Just combine both operations you mentioned. The following code will solve your problem:
gatt_before = b'0f 18 '  # your bytes string
s = gatt_before.decode('utf-8')  # or any other suitable encodings
s = s.replace(' ', '')  # remove all whitespace
i = int(s, 16)  # convert string of hex digits into integer via int() with base 16\
print(i)  # print output
print('%')

Of course, you can also place this into a function, which I strongly recommend  for the sake of readability and reusability. The above code refactored into a function:
def convert_bytes_hex_string_to_int(bytes_hex_str):
    s = bytes_hex_str.decode('utf-8')  # or any other suitable encodings
    s = s.replace(' ', '')  # remove all whitespace
    i = int(s, 16)  # convert string of hex digits into integer via int() with base 16\
    return i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(convert_bytes_hex_string_to_int(b'0f 18'))
    print('%')

Now you can use this conversion technique whenever and wherever you want.
